# How to get a list of words in a doc by TF/IDF scores

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I have an ElasticSearch index. Given a document ID in the index, I want to get a list of words in the doc by TF-IDF scores. Is that possible to write an ES query to get the list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could retrieve the list of all terms in the document and then use explain while searching for all words in the document.

Ex:
If the document contains foo and bar, query would be:

```
/MY_INDEX/MY_TYPE/_search?q=_id:MY_ID foo bar&explain=true&size=1
```

In the score explanation you will see the idf score and the tf score for each word.